Challenges with High-Order Boundary Conditions in PDEs for Beam Vibration Analysis in Mathematica
I am trying to solve a problem involving the longitudinal vibration of a beam in Mathematica. The beam is fixed at the left end and has a concentrated mass at the right end. The system is subjected to a harmonic force excitation at the right end. The following figure shows the details of my setup:

And here are my codes
(* Parameters *)
L = 1;
rho = 1;
A = 1;
Emodulus = 1;
M = 1;

(* PDE for longitudinal vibration *)
pde = rho*D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] == Emodulus*D[u[x, t], {x, 2}];

(* Boundary conditions *)
bc1 = u[0, t] == 0;
bc2 = (Emodulus*A*Derivative[1, 0][u][L, t] + M*Derivative[0, 2][u][L, t]) == Sin[t];

(* Initial conditions *)
ic1 = u[x, 0] == 0;
ic2 = Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == 0;

(* Solving the PDE *)
solution = NDSolve[{pde, bc1, bc2, ic1, ic2}, u[x, t], {x, 0, L}, {t, 0, 10}];

However, I encounter an error related to the boundary conditions involving the second derivative in time. I understand that introducing a second-order time derivative in the boundary condition might be problematic since it matches the order of the PDE.
Could someone help me figure out how to properly set up and solve this problem in Mathematica?
Thank you in advance!

Your second BC does not look right. You have in it second derivative in time? or did you make typo?

@Nasser Thanks for your attention. Actually I made typo since I missed a superscript 2 on t. It should be the second derivative in time. Now I have made corrections to the picture.

But you have second order in time as highest derivative in the PDE. So you can't really impose constraints with same order as the highest one on the equation. It has to be one less less.

@Nasser So I am seeking advice on how to deal with this issue. Such boundary condition origins from the mechanical properties of the model and cannot be changed easily. I am wondering if there exists any mathematical or numerical tricks to overcome such challenge.

You will get error The differential order of the functions in the initial or boundary conditions should be strictly less than in the differential equations if you try. (I have not, but this is what should happen. see related question too-high-differential-order-in-boundary-conditions

This problem can be solved with the Method of Lines as follows
U[tm_] := 
 Module[{L = 1, dy = 1/10, A = 1, rho = 1, Emod = 1, M = 1}, 
  xgrid = Range[0, L, dy]; nx = Length[xgrid];
  M2 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], xgrid, 
     DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix"; 
  M1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], xgrid, 
     DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
  u = Table[uu[i][t], {i, nx}]; eq = rho  D[u, t, t] - Emod  M2 . u;
  (*PDE for longitudinal vibration*)
  (*Boundary conditions*)
  eq[[1]] = D[u[[1]], t, t];
  eq[[-1]] = Emod  A  (M1 . u)[[-1]] + M  D[u[[-1]], t, t] - Sin[t];
  
  (*Initial conditions*)
  ic = Join[u, D[u, t]] /. t -> 0; eqs = Join[eq, ic];
  sol = NDSolve[Table[eqs[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqs]}], 
    u, {t, 0, tm}]; sol]

Function U usage for $0\le t\le 10$
s10 = U[10];

Visualization at different x=xgrid
Plot[Evaluate[u /. s10[[1]]], {t, 0, 10}, PlotLegends -> N[xgrid], 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]



clever (as so often)

Thank you! Your method has solved my problem perfectly!
